# Getting value from another component

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a possibility I can pass an event to other components without getting the selector of the component?

Comment: Please share information about your structure. There are several ways from `output` to `service`. There are special library which can be check depending on our needs and your project / component structure.

Comment: I’m using output event emitter. But is there anyway I can get the value to multiple components without getting the selector of the component?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

yes, the most popular solution is to use a service, inject it into both components, and create props on the service so u can store data on it , now you can access these props from both components,
you should also use 'BehaviorSubject' so you can subscribe if data changed.

[here is an example for it](https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2019/04/23/how-to-use-angular-services-to-share-data-between-components/)

[Using Behavior Subject with Rxjs](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/how-to-share-data-between-components-in-angular-4i60)

I wrote an example for you

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareDataService {
 public sharedData :BehaviorSubject<number>= new BehaviorSubject(0);
  constructor() { }
}
```

First Component (will change data)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ShareDataService } from '../share-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css']
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  firstModel: number;
  constructor(private dataService: ShareDataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  changeDataOnTheSecondComp(input) {
    console.log(input);
    this.dataService.sharedData.next(input.value)
  }
}
```

will receive changed data

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ShareDataService } from '../share-data.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-second',
  templateUrl: './second.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second.component.css']
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

  secondModel: number;
  constructor(private dataService: ShareDataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.sharedData.subscribe(x => {
      this.secondModel = x;
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: To give you more of the overview. I have a toggle switcher(parent component) that I want to put in the navmenu(child). I was able to access it in the child but I want to access it on another component without calling the parent selector. I just want the value of the event.

Comment: ok , I see , you should create a service and add a public 'BehaviorSubject' to it
then inject that service to any component you want to change or get its data. this will make you change data from one component and view 'subscribe' data from another

Comment: I wrote an example for you, does it match your case?

Comment: Can I message you?

Comment: yes of course , i would like to help